# AutoMapper LLBLGEN entity class error model to entity > -> SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.IPrefetchPath

Tags: automapper, llblgenpro, llblgen

I use LLBLGEN, I want to map the entity class with the c # class.

```
    Mapper.CreateMap<Model.Location, EntityClasses.LocationEntity>();
    Mapper.CreateMap<EntityClasses.LocationEntity, Model.Location>();
```

EntityClasses.LocationEntity loEntity = LocationEntity.Query.Where(s => s.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault();
     Model.Location model = Mapper.Map(loEntity);

model fills no problem. but model map entity object error

LocationEntity locationEntity = Mapper.Map(model);
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
Location -> IPrefetchPath
Model.Location -> SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.IPrefetchPath

Destination path:
LocationEntity

Source value:
Model.Location

What is a problem ?